# What are the GKE (with IP alias enabled) pod/service IP ranges?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to use terraform to create a GKE cluster, but I am stuck because, for the pod / services subnetworks, I do not know which values GKE uses by default for the primary IP range and secondary IP range.

In the below terraform configuration, what are the default GKE values for:

```
google_compute_subnetwork.pods.ip_range
google_compute_subnetwork.pods.secondary_ip_range.ip_range
google_compute_subnetwork.services.ip_range
google_compute_subnetwork.services.secondary_ip_range.ip_range
```

?

---

```
resource "google_compute_network" "primary" {
    name                    = "${var.cluster_name}"
    auto_create_subnetworks = false
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "pods" {
    name          = "pods-primary"
    region        = "${var.region}"
    ip_cidr_range = ""
    network       = "${google_compute_network.primary.self_link}"

    secondary_ip_range {
        range_name    = "pods-secondary"
        ip_cidr_range = ""
    }
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "services" {
    name          = "services-primary"
    region        = "${var.region}"
    ip_cidr_range = ""
    network       = "${google_compute_network.primary.self_link}"

    secondary_ip_range {
        range_name    = "services-secondary"
        ip_cidr_range = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The GKE default values for the primary IP range and secondary IP range are based on
[image: Pods and Services ranges]

If you need to customize these values, please follow these [guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips#cluster_sizing)

About what CIDRs will be used, if not provided by the user, GKE will allocate a random /14 block from 10.0.0.0/8 (except from 10.128.0.0/9 if the cluster is in the default network).

This range is the Pod range for the cluster. When a node is added to a GKE cluster, a /24 block is allocated from the Pod range and assigned to the node.

For route-based clusters, the final /20 block of a cluster IP range is set aside for IP addresses for services using a ClusterIP, and is not available for node allocation blocks.

For alias IPs clusters, a separate /20 block outside of the Pod range is reserved for services using a secondary range.

Comment: my question is what are the cidr values for the primary and secondartys for pod/service. i am aware that they are based on those values, but that table does not include the cidrs

Comment: @snkcld Added this info to my answer.

Comment: why would an IP from the pod range be assigned to the node and not the node range? Any reference?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, with vpc native, there is no default cidr range defined

Comment: Yes and suggested ranges are 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 or 192.168.0.0/16.
How do you break these CIDR range such that they can used in pod and services ranges? For eg 192.168.0.0/16, I want to use this CIDR for pod and services. How to do that?